# Create a query that shows a total value only (image attached)

Tags: sql, excel, ms-access, sum

[image: My query image]

Hi, I'm new to MS-Access. My apologies in advance, this is probably a basic question asked and answered but I don't know how to word the search to find the right results.

I have this query on MS-Access. Is it possible to create a query only with the ***sum value***, 662766.48??? Below is my code.

```
SELECT Sum(T.DollarsSold) 
FROM T
HAVING (((T.Year)="2017") AND ((T.Period)="08"));
```

My ultimate goal is exporting only the sum value of a query to a specific cell in an existing excel spreadsheet. And I thought It'd be easier to have just a sum value on a query and export it to excel.

Comment: Sum of which field? T.DollarsSold? And this query isn't valid to begin with. Shouldn't that be `T.Period = "08"` in your HAVING clause?

Comment: Why do you include table/query T twice? Try: `SELECT Sum(DollarsSold) AS SumSold FROM T HAVING [Year]="2017" AND Period="08";` Year is a reserved word and should not use reserved words as names for anything. Use the query designer to build query. Select Totals (looks like Sigma) from the ribbon.

Comment: The sum of the colum, T.DollarsSold. If you see the image, the sum value is in the far down left.  Thank you for pointing that out. I must have typed it wrong. Will edit! @JacobH

Comment: @June7 sorry as I was changing names of the tables in the code, I have put it that way. my mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just sum the DollarsSold column, and change the `HAVING` to `WHERE`, since you're getting rid of the `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT sum(DollarsSold)
FROM Table_S
WHERE Year="2017" AND Period="08";
```

Comment: I tried "SELECT Sum(dbo_SO_RecapByProductLineWhse.DollarsSold) AS Expr1
FROM dbo_IM_ProductLine
WHERE ((([Year])="2017") AND (([Period])="08"));" then it was giving me 'eneter paramter value' pop-ups.. I don't want any pop-up window

Comment: Thank you so much for the edit! Now It does work! Thank you so much to both of you!